# JSON parsing help (Native Android, java)

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, parsing

I am trying to do JSON parsing. The JSON data is shown below, I am trying to get the "categories". I was able to JSON parse everything else, but I am not sure what does this "categories" belong to, is it a JSONObject, JSONArray, or something else? I am a newbie and self-taught, usually I am familiar that JSONArray has form of "JSONArray": {["content"]}, and the "content" is JSONObject. But in this case, "categories":["content"]. I am trying to parse this "categories", and turn it to string. Thank you for your help.

```
{
   "results": [
   {
      "type": "Restaurant",
      "id": "jfhuiewjkfkdljiahueijkfnlsdiejkl1484391hjk8421k",
      "score": 99.9844207764,
      "dist": 15.581982823437135,
      "info": "search:ta:840369014527642-US",
      "poi": {
         "name": "RoofTop Bar",
         "categorySet": [
         {
            "id": 184729472943
         }
      ],
      "categories": [
         "pub food",
         "restaurant"
      ]}
   }]
}
```

This is what I have tried:

```
groups = new JSONArray(); 
groups = response.getJSONArray("results");
if (groups.length() > 0) {
   JSONObject resultObject = groups.getJSONObject(0);
   if (resultObject.has("poi")) {
      if (resultObject.getJSONObject("poi").has("name")) {
         nameResult = resultObject.getJSONObject("poi").getString("name");
      } else {
         nameResult = "Information is not available.";
      }
      if (resultObject.getJSONObject("poi").has("categories")) {
         JSONObject categoriesResult;
         categoriesResult = resultObject.getJSONObject("categories").toString();
      }
```

Comment: this json is not a valid.. the "poi" object isnt closed.

Comment: I just edited it, it should be complete now.

Comment: Try something like https://jsonlint.com/ to ensure your JSON is valid. It's still failing. Notepad++ also has a nice plugin "JSON Viewer" which has a "Format JSON" that will validate it.

Comment: Hi, the JSON should be valid, I was able to get information for the other information, such as the the name. But I am just not familiar with the format of the "categories".

Comment: @Brian McCanaugh - with complicated if/else blocks .. you can inadvertently cause a lot of *LOGIC* errors when you fail to *INDENT* correctly.  Just saying...

Comment: @BrianMcCanaugh your JSON looks good now. Are you still having issues?

Comment: Yes, I am still having issues just for the "categories". I don't think I was able to set categoriesResult = resultObject.getJSONObject("categories").toString();
and also cannot get: categoriesResult = resultObject.getJSONArray("categories").toString();

Comment: I figured it out. I just used .get("categories"). The simplest way is the best.

Answer (score 0):

- `results` is an array of objects
- The first object contains a property called `poi`
- `poi` contains a property called `categories`

So using the top to bottom approach, we can arrive at

```
const categoriesArray = results[0].poi.categories; // gives categories as an array of strings

const categoriesString = categoriesArray.join(",") // gives categories as string, with comma separated values
```

Comment: Hi, would I get categories = "pub food, restaurant" by doing your recommendation? I have edited my question including what I have tried in Android Studio.

Comment: Hi @BrianMcCanaugh. Please find my edited answer. There, `categoriesString` is what you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it is the actual raw data but the poi object where the categories are contained is malformed. It is missing a closing bracket which could be causing parsing issues.

That apart, the field categories from the poi object is a list of strings I am not sure how you want to format it to a string but you could loop through them and do want you want with them.

In order to obtain them you can access them from your object with `results[0].poi.categories` or loop through the results before accessing the categories with `result.poi.categories` where `result` is the variable containing the currently looped result.

EDIT:

From your code sample, assuming response is a JSONObject you can do the following.

Then to obtain categories in a string without the array format, you can loop through the categories and concatenate them to a string.

```
String categories = resultObject.get("categories").join(", ");
```

Comment: Hi, would I get categories = "pub food, restaurant" by doing your recommendation? I have edited my question including what I have tried in Android Studio.

Comment: Currently you would get a string representing the array which will look like "[\"pub food\", \"restaurant\"]" if you want what you mentioned you would have to loop through the array and concatenate them to a string using the toString on a category.

Comment: Hi, I did try to use the toString method. But I got an error stating along the line "cannot find categories". I failed to get the content of "categories" by using getJSONObject and also getJSONArray.

Comment: I have updated my anwser according to your needs. Could you share the full exception message that you are having with resultObject.getJSONArray("categories") ?

Comment: I figured it out. I just used .get("categories"). Thank you for the help.

Comment: Glad to hear that out. Then using join method instead of toString should get you the string you are looking for.